# Finding all positive integer solutions to $\log_BA - \log_AB=\log_{\sqrt A}A^B$, with $A<100$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am stuck on a Logarithm Question given to one of my friends.

> Given
> $$\log_BA - \log_AB=\log_{\sqrt A}A^B$$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive integers with $A<100$.
>
> Compute all possible ordered pairs $(A, B)$.

I initially tried this on my own but found myself stuck. I am very confused on where I should start or what I should really even do to solve something like this.

Comment: Maybe start by observing that $\log_{A^{1/2}}A^B=B\log_{\sqrt{A}}A=2B$

Comment: And $\log_x y = { \ln y \over \ln x}$.

Comment: What is bigger: $A$ or $B$?

Comment: I would also double-check the problem setup (ideally try to fix your post to use MathJax, please!) I have run a Python program to do an exhaustive search for pairs $(A,B)$ of this sort and have found none, so I am now suspecting that there is something fishy in the problem statement itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem doesn't state which is larger. I did get the part about 2b and made the bases the same but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: Ty for the tips, I will try to fix this post sorry if it's messy, I'm just new here.

Comment: @MIDEKSAGONFA I *know* (i.e. can conclude that) $A$ should be bigger, because if $A<B$ then $\log_B A-\log_A B<0$. Thus, as $A<100$ we have $B\le A<100$ as well, and so we are left with finitely many possibilities (at most about $100\times 100$, in fact about half as many!). I don't need to know a deep theorem (as in the present answers) and I can still (with the help of a computer) check them all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base $1$ the logarithm is not defined, so we may assume $A,B\geq 2$.

By the base change formula we have $\log_BA=\frac{\log_AA}{\log_AB}=\frac{1}{\log_AB}$. Combining this with the observation of **Stinking Bishop** that $\log_{A^{1/2}}A^B=2B$ we can rewrite:
$$
\frac{1}{\log_AB}-\log_AB=2B.
$$

Fixing $A$ for the moment and looking at $f_A(x)=\frac{1}{\log_Ax}-\log_Ax$, we see that $f_A'(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln(A)(\log_Ax)^2x}-\frac{1}{\ln(A)x}$. For $x>1$ we have $f'_A(x)<0$.

This means, for fixed $A$, the LHS $\frac{1}{\log_AB}-\log_AB$ strictly monotonically decreasing in $B$ and the RHS $2B$ strictly monotonically increasing in $B$, therefore to each $A$ at most one real solution $B$ and thus also only at most one integer solution $B$. Furthermore since $f(A)=0<2A$ we additionally get that necessarily $B<A$.

Thus: we have for each $A\geq 2$ at most one $B\geq 2$ that solves the equation.

Now comes a rather heavy and deep result, a corollary of the [Gelfand-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem): $\log_AB=\frac{\ln A}{\ln B}$ is either (a) transcendental or (b) rational. In case (a) the expression $\frac{1}{\log_AB}-\log_AB$ is also transcendental and therefore never equal to the integer $2B$. In case (b) we have for some integers $p,q$:
$$
log_AB=\frac{\ln A}{\ln B}=\frac{p}{q}\Leftrightarrow
q\ln A=p\ln B\Leftrightarrow
\ln A^q=\ln B^p\Leftrightarrow
A^q=B^p.
$$

All together this means we need to look for $1<B<A$ such that there are integers $p,q$ with $A^q=B^p$. Looking at prime factorizations of $A$ and $B$ we get that $A,B$ need to have the same prime factors and even more in the same proportion: If $p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots p_k^{a_k}$ is a prime factorization of $A$ the prime factorization of $B$ must look like $p_1^{ac_1}\cdot\ldots p_k^{ca_k}$ for some rational proportionality constant $c<1$. In particular every prime factor of a candidate $A$ must have multiplicity at least $2$

Since we are given $A<100$ this leaves just a few candidates for $(A,B)$ namely:
$$
\{(4,2),(8,2),(8,4),(9,3),(16,2),(16,4),(16,8),(25,5),(27,3),(27,9),(36,6),(49,7),(64,2),(64,4),(64,8),(64,16),(64,32),(81,3),(81,9),(81,27)\}
$$

This list of $20$ pairs can be checked by hand. None of them is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log_{B}A=t.$ Obviously $t>1$

$t^2-2Bt-1=0\implies t=B+\sqrt{B^2+1}\implies A=B^{B+\sqrt{B^2+1}}$

$\implies \frac{A}{B^B}=B^{\sqrt{B^2+1}}$

As LHS is rational and RHS is transcendental by Gelfand-Schneider theorem, it has no solution in integers.

Comment: The last step is justified by the [Gelfand-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) and is rather nontrivial. I tried to expand on that in my own answer, but could restrict only to a set of candidates making use of the bound $A<100$. Can you be more explicit about your last implication? Clearly the expression $B+\sqrt{B^2+1}$ being irrational for any integer $B$ should be part of such a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Anyway with the expression $A=B^{B+\sqrt{B^2+1}}$ and using monotonicity in $B$, it is straight forward to see that $A\geq 100$ for any $B\geq 3$. Since $A=B=1$ are forbidden because of the definition of the logarithms, this leaves only $B=2$, which clearly does not produce a solution. Your approach gives a much quicker solution for the original question for $A<100$.

Comment: In my solution it has no solution for all $A>B>1>$ I edited